# How to connect Spotfire with Hive

Tags: hive, bigdata

I am trying to connect Spotfirw with Hive. I have installed jar files in the tomcat/lib folder but the server goes down.

Please help me with this if anyone has already connect spotfire with Hive.

Answer (score -1):

There is no in-built database template for Hive database.So if you have written it then it is good.After that you have to paste the desired JDBC(.JAR file) inside the Lib folder of Spotfire server installation directory.Save the configuration & restart the the Spotfire server service.

If still your server is down the check the Catalina & Server log files.

Hope it helps you.

Regards
Manoj Singh